# Take subsets of number and check if they add up to target sum in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, lisp, subset, racket, subset-sum

I want to write a function called `sumToN` that takes as input a list of numbers `L` and a target number `T` and returns every subset of numbers in `L` that adds up to exactly `T`.   These subsets must be returned in a particular order (as shown in the examples below).

e.g input `((sumToN 6 '(1 2 3 4 5)))`

e.g output `(((2 4) (1 5) (1 2 3)))`

i have this so far

```
(define sumToN
  (lambda (T L)
    (cond
      [(null? L)                '() ]
      [(null? (cdr L))                (checkEqual T (list(car L))) ]
      [#t (checkEqual T (+(cadr L)(car L)))]
     )
   )
 )

;; creating helper function called checkEqual
(define checkEqual
  (lambda (T L)
    (cond
      [(equal? T (car L))                (L) ]
      [#t '()]
     )
   )
 )
```

Answer (score 3):

Racket makes this trivial:

```lisp
(define (sumToN t l)
  (sequence->list
    (sequence-filter (lambda (combo) (= (apply + combo) t))
                     (in-combinations l))))
(sumToN 6 '(1 2 3 4 5)) ; => ((1 2 3) (2 4) (1 5))
```

Getting the desired order is left as an exercise for the reader (Especially since you don't say what the rules for ordering are).